# Why can't I solve for this second derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Here's the equation I have to find the second derivative point for.

$$f(x)=\frac{x+2}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{x-2}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

From here I then calculate the second derivative and set it equal to 0.
But it doesn't work.. Take a look:

$$f''(x)=\frac{-x^\frac{3}{2} + 6x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{4x^{3}} = 0$$
FROM first DERIVATIVE TO second:

$$\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}[x-2]'-((x-2)[2x^{\frac{3}{2}}]'}{4x^{3}}$$

$$\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} -3x^{}\frac{3}{2}+6x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{4x^{3}}=0$$
$$-x^{\frac{3}{2}} + 6x^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0$$
$$(-x^{\frac{3}{2}})^{2} + (6x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2}$$
$$x^{3} + 36x = 0$$
$$x (x^{2} + 36) = 0$$
$$x = 0  \text{   or    } x^{2} = - 36 \text{      no solution..}$$

This doesn't seem right.. Yet I have no idea why. It's easier to write the function as a product but I want to solve it using the quotient rule..
What's going on?

Comment: Never mind that.

Comment: Why do you say that this "doesn't seem right"?

Comment: Why should you expect to be *able* to solve it?  Not every function has an inflection point.  Take for example $\frac{1}{2}x^2$ whose second derivative is identically equal to $1$ and is never zero.

Comment: This one has an inflection point when you write it as a product.. I'm confused as hell.

Comment: Perhaps you could show your work in the quotient rule, your numerator looks suspicious to me.  It looks almost like you forgot to multiply by the $-2$.

Comment: I've reworked this problem 5 times. Can;t find it with quotient rule. Please help.

Comment: Instead of writing it as $f(x)=\frac{x+2}{x^{1/2}}$ it may be easier to write it as $f(x)=x^{1/2}+2x^{-1/2}$

Comment: I know.. But I can't reproduce the same result with the quotient rule.. That's what I want to do. And solve for 0.

Comment: Please include your work so that we can find where the error is.  If you don't include your work, it's hard for us to help you without doing the problem.

Comment: Your numerator in the second derivative should be $-x^{3/2}+6x^{1/2}$

Comment: I find it significantly easier to divide the original expression by the denominator fully to get $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$, then find the subsequent derivatives.

Comment: Now, if you split up your fraction and realize that $\frac{x^{3/2}}{x^3}=x^{-3/2}$ and $\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^3}=x^{-5/2}$, you should get the answer that you're looking for.

Comment: What I did was: $(-x^{\frac{3}{2}})^{2} + (6x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2}$ after cancelling the numerator by multiplying $4x^{3}$.

Comment: Then I got: $x^{3} + 36x = 0$ which is not a solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We proceed via the quotient rule:

$$f''(x)=\frac{2x^{3/2}-(x-2)3x^{1/2}}{4x^3}=\frac{2x^{3/2}-3x^{3/2}+6x^{1/2}}{4x^3}=x^{1/2}\left(\frac{6-x}{4x^3}\right)=\frac{6-x}{4x^{5/2}}$$

We can set $f''(x)=0$ and find that $f''(6)=0$. To find the points of inflection, we simply need to test a point less than and greater than $x=6$.

Comment: Hey Thanks! I got the exact same thing as you did. But what If I do not factor out the $x^{1/2}$ and instead cancel the numerator (the lower part of the fraction) and then do the following: $(-x^{\frac{3}{2}})^{2} + (6x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2}$ Is this valid?

Comment: In general, $a^2+b^2 \neq (a+b)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer that you expect, but a simple way to get the correct answer.

$$f(x)=x^{1/2}+2x^{-1/2},$$

$$f'(x)=\frac12x^{-1/2}-x^{-3/2},$$

$$f''(x)=-\frac14x^{-3/2}+\frac32x^{-5/2}.$$

Multiplying by $-4x^{-5/2}$, the inflection point is at $x-6=0$.